# How to add a simple onClick function callback to a astro component?

Tags: astrojs

I would love to know how to do a simple astro component with a callback function onClick

my Button.astro component:

```
---
type Props = {
  title: string;
  className?: string;
  id: string;
  onClick?: () => void;
};
const { title, className, id, onClick } = Astro.props;
---

<!-- type==module faz com que o script só seja executado quando o DOM for inicializado. Isso dispensa ter que colocar a tag script abaixo do html -->
<button id={id} title={title} class={className}>
  <span class="sr-only">{title}</span>
  <slot />
</button>

<script define:vars={{ id, onClick }} type="module">
  console.warn("id", id, onClick, document.querySelector("#" + id));

  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("click", onClick);
</script>
```

use:

```
<Button
    title="title"
    id="test-button"
    onClick={() => console.log("encontrou o elemento")}
  >
    Clique-me!
  </Button>
```

it keeps saying that onClick is undefined on browser console.

OBS: I am using the Button in a component that has client:load directive

I am using typescript. I dont want to add to the window a global function and neither pass a plain text to call a global function.

I would love to do a simple onClick callback like any other framework.

How it is possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: "I am using the Button in a component that has client:load directive". You cannot use Astro components inside components written in other frameworks (react, etc). You would need to create a button component in React or whatever framework you are using. This is because Astro components are purely server side components and aren't loaded on the client side.

Comment: hi, @randombits.dev. The button component I am talking is a astro component. I am not using any other framework besides astro. How would you do a astro button component, that recieves a id(dynamic button) with a onClick as a callback function like in react for example?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/#pass-frontmatter-variables-to-scripts):

*In Astro components, the code in the [frontmatter](https://docs.astro.build/en/basics/astro-components/#the-component-script) between the --- fences runs on the server and is not available in the browser.*

Astro components are server-side, which means they operate/run in a server context. Whatever you pass to them (which you will receive in the frontmatter) is coming from a server context.

When it comes to functions, Astro will not be able to serialize server functions to client ones. You'll have to integrate a UI framework to be able to pass functions props to the client.